# How can make valid date with SOAPpy?

Tags: python, soappy

I have the folloving SOAP code, and from server I become as answer: 
invalid endDate

Here is my code:

```
from SOAPpy import WSDL2 as WSDL
from SOAPpy import Types
from lxml import etree

url = 'http://www.mnb.hu/arfolyamok.asmx?wsdl'
namespace = 'http://www.mnb.hu'
inp = Types.dateType(name=(namespace, '2015,04,15'))
out = Types.dateType(name=(namespace, '2015,04,17'))

server = WSDL.Proxy(url, namespace=namespace)
server.soapproxy.config.debug = 1

server.GetExchangeRates(startDate=inp,endDate=out,currencyNames='RUB,CNY')
```

On debug I see: `2015-04-17Z`, why is Z on end the date?

Comment: It might be helpful to post the error message in more detail, as well.

Comment: <GetExchangeRatesResult>&lt;MNBExchangeRates&gt;&lt;Error&gt;Invalid endDate&lt;/Error&gt;&lt;/MNBExchangeRates&gt;</GetExchangeRatesResult></GetExchangeRatesResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

Answer (score 0):

The Z in `2015-04-17Z` specifies the timezone - 'Z' is shorthand for Zulu Time, or UTC.

See http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp for more detail about SOAP date/time formats.

Comment: And how can it remove, or giving without time zone, while in official doc is:It is advisable to specify the dates in form of
year-month-day (separated by hyphens or dots), the currency names
should be specified by their abbreviated three-letter names
(capital letters), separated by commas. Example for requesting a
query:

GetExchangeRates=("2014-07-14", "2014-07-16", "RUB,SGD");